# Phonegap and making use of Plugins (specifically the Facebook Plugin)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm now at my wits ends with Phonegap and its Plugins!!

I have created an a Phonegap app and it works and it runs well on android. I now wish to simply use the Facebook JS SDK. I have been using the plugin found [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin). But I keep constantly running into 100 different errors.

The code in the ConnectPlugin.java is saying that Plugins has been deprecated. But I'm using Cordova 2.3.0 and in the Cordova 2.3.0.jar the Plugin.java class exists as seen in the picture below:

[image]

I'm really not sure what on Earth to do now to get this plugin to work? I have tried everything and have searched the net for hours with no working solution. I just need the Facebook plugin to work. Please any help would really be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you ever have any plugin problems ie there is complainant about the Plugin Class as above, then at least for Facebook this problem has been solved [here](https://github.com/Raffaello/phonegap-facebook-plugin)